# Data aggregation in Redshift to improve performance

Tags: amazon-redshift, olap-cube

I'm using heavily loaded Redshift cluster with some complex views that joins huge tables, during the pick hours many user query these views which is causing some performance issues, I used metalized views to pre-calculate some joins and aggregations but it didn't worked for me as they don't refresh properly, also I used different sort key since Redshift doesn't have index but this solution didn't improve performance as well, so I'm thinking to use some aggregated tables to simulate something like OLAP cubes to improve performance of queries, any thought or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You mention "complex views" and one of the biggest performance stealers I have seen is poorly written queries.  Looped joins, massive expansion of data then DISTINCT, and repeated full table scans can make any query very slow.  I'm not saying these things are going on but it is worth making sure that queries are optimal before investing in extensive changes.

You don't mention distribution keys of your tables.  This can have a large impact on cluster performance.   The wrong DISTKEY and your data may have transit the cluster network many times during query execution.  Ensuring "node local" actions when the data set is large (early in the query) can save a lot of time in execution.

You mention "peak hours" when the performance of you views is most noticeable.  Is it just you views running at these peak times or are the other heavy load activity going on?  You see Redshift has a number of attributes that are shared between all queries running that can be overloaded by the total workload.  In these cases queries that run just fine become too slow due to the over-use of shared attributes by these other workloads.  These greedy queries could be major contributors to your issue.  You'll generally be looking for queries that have high use of the network and/or the disks.  There are a few other places that greedy queries hit Redshift but these are the most common two.

Materialized views is a good path to try. You say the didn't refresh properly.  Is there a separate issue to look into here or is there some general limitation in your case?  Getting the materialized views to work could be a winner but you may have already exhausted this path and know there is no fix that will work in your case.

Summary / aggregate tables is a fine solution but comes with some costs.  First you need to generated the needed summaries and keep then up to date.  You will also need to get your users to move to using these summaries instead of the base data.  There is a fair amount of work in defining, updating, and ensuring data consistency between these summary tables.  I'd want to make sure I've done all the meaningful optimizations before biting this off.

As a start I'd make some summaries of cluster load by aggregating information from these system tables:

- stl_nestloop
- stl_scan (look for scan amount to perm tables and internal working tables)
- stl_dist
- stl_return
- stl_wlm_query
- stl_commit_stats

You will want to aggregate to understand which queries are taking a long time / using a lot of resources during these peak times.  Are queries using your views tying up resources or are they victims of other greedy queries.